# Android action buttons are not showing in action bar, but they are in overflow menu

Tags: android

I just started to follow the tutorial from google for making Android apps.
At the moment I'm trying to make the action buttons work:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

The buttons do show up in the overflow menu but (even though I did everything from the tutorial right) the button itself doesn't show...

I've been searching for a long time now, finding other people with a similar problem, but non of those provided a solution that worked for me...)

[Actions Buttons in Android not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058975/actions-buttons-in-android-not-visible)

[Android actionbar not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950960/android-actionbar-not-visible)

**Edit:**

```
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Post your menu xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO make an item appear directly in the action bar instead of the overflow use the yourapp:showAsAction ="ifRoom" just like the last line below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Set the show as action property to `always`

`android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]`

Comment: user3249477 is right though. For a proper response, please post your xml.

Comment: Just posted it and I already set it on 'always', did nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

If your application's name is "MyApp" then your code should be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:MyApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          MyApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

</menu>
```